# Add push notifications to Visual Studio Cordova Project

Tags: azure-mobile-services, visual-studio-cordova

I tried to follow this article on MSDN magazine [enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879353.aspx) to add iOS push notifications. However the sample code they provide [enter link description here](https://github.com/Azure/mobile-services-samples/tree/master/CordovaNotificationsArticle) is outdated(using VS2013). I tried to migrate the project to VS2015 by following [enter link description here](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/master/known-issues/known-issues-vs2015.md) but still cannot get it to work.

Can anyone provide a working sample code in VS2015? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the sample to Visual Studio 2015 in my fork: https://github.com/ggailey777/mobile-services-samples/tree/master/CordovaNotificationsArticle
To get it to work, I also needed to add the Whitelist plugin, which is now a requirement to access remote services from a Cordova app. 
I am waiting to merge it back into the upstream fork until after I can get it tested on iOS (it does work now on Android). As mostafa points out, you do also need to follow the steps to configure push notification for iOS, which includes doing a bunch of stuff in Xcode on the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the notification hub to send notifications to your iOS app.

Here is a sample how to do this in step by step walk-through:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-get-started/

Hope this helps.